# How can I debug the time used by a function?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am loading a big Pandas Data frame into memory. I can measure the time needed with the `%%time` magic:

```
%%time
df = pd.read_csv(data_file)

CPU times: user 3min 53s, sys: 57.5 s, total: 4min 50s
Wall time: 21min 2s
```

There are about 16 minutes that the system is giving the CPU to other processes. I know that my process will not take 100% of the time ([Difference between CPU time and wall time](https://service.futurequest.net/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/407)). But, because this is a Virtual Machine used exclusively by me, I guess that most of the 16 minutes are related to processes involved with the data loading task.

If I make a visual check of the resources used with `htop`, most of the cores are idle, and the system increases the amount of Swap memory slowly. I guess that the I/O operations to Swap are taking most of the time, but I want to confirm it.

I would like to see if there is something I can do to improve the reading process, but I do not know how to look into the time spent inside the `read_csv` function.

**Edit**: Thanks to Ori's answer, I could figure out that most of the time was spent on Pandas's `internals.py _stack_arrays()` method and the `read` call of the object `pandas.parser.TextReader`. Were Pandas figuring out the column type? I tried providing a dictionary with types, and the load time was reduced to 3 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would offer a use of a profiler for such cases.

> Profiling a Python program is doing a dynamic analysis that measures
>   the execution time of the program and everything that compose it. That
>   means measuring the time spent in each of its functions. This will
>   give you data about where your program is spending time, and what area
>   might be worth optimizing.

For example, you can use the [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/profile.html) library. An extended explanation can be found [here](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2015/guide-to-python-profiling-cprofile-concrete-case-carbonara).